# MutationObserver передача аргументов между абстракцией видимости

Tags: javascript

Написал по быстрому такую функцию и встал в тупик.

```
function observerElementDOM(selection, func, status) {
        const target = document.querySelector(selection);
        const observer =  new MutationObserver(func);

        const settings = status ?
            {
                childList: true,
                subtree: true,
                characterDataOldValue: true
            }
            :
            {
                childList: true,
                subtree: false,
                characterDataOldValue: false
            }

        observer.observe(target, settings);
    }
```

Есть функция, которую я прокидываю вроде:

```
 function changeHeight(alterations, observer) {
        console.log(target);
        alterations.forEach(alteration => {
            console.log(alteration);
        })
    }
```

Cитуация в том, что мне нужно получить доступ к `console.log(target);` о которой не знает эта функция.

Вариант тупа создать target  глобально не подходит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько понял, вам нужно что-то вроде этого.

```
function observerElementDOM(selection, func, status) {
    const target = document.querySelector(selection);
    const observer =  new MutationObserver(function(alterations, observer){
      func(target, alterations, observer)
    });

    const settings = status ?
        {
            childList: true,
            subtree: true,
            characterDataOldValue: true
        }
        :
        {
            childList: true,
            subtree: false,
            characterDataOldValue: false
        }

    observer.observe(target, settings);
}

function changeHeight(target, alterations, observer) {
    console.log(target);
    alterations.forEach(alteration => {
        console.log(alteration);
    })
}
```

Comment: Лучший ответ Спасибо!.